# Explanation why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ = $\frac{-\pi^2}{12}$ with Euler's $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: real-analysis

Can somebody explain why the sum is $\frac{-\pi^2}{12}$. Can you somehow use the zeta function? If so, how?

Comment: Euler's sum is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: Of course, you are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's add them together:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n+1}{n^2}$$

and for odd $n$, $(-1)^n+1=0$ and for even $n$, $(-1)^n+1=2$, so this rewrites to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2n)^2}$$

which simplifies to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful.

Comment: Actually, how did you get $(2n)^2$ from $n^2+n^2$?

Comment: @JulianBuchel well, the odd terms cancel out, so we're left with only the even terms ($\frac{2}{n^2}$ with $n$ even), that is, $\frac{2}{(2n)^2}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n)^2}-\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n)^2}-\big(\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}-\frac14\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}\big)$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n)^2}-\frac34\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$$

$$=\frac14\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}-\frac34\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$$

$$=-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like this approach too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on step 2 to 3?

Comment: $1/1^2+1/3^2+1/5^2+\dots=1/1^2+1/2^2+1/3^3+\dots-1/4(1/1^2+1/2^2+1/3^2+\dots$